# How to trigger Real Mouse Click on page reload?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
 angular.element(document).ready(function () {
   angular.element("#myDiv").click(function (e) {
      if(e.hasOwnProperty('originalEvent')){
        console.log('REAL MOUSE CLICK');
      }
      else{
        console.log('FAKE CLICK');
      }
    });
    angular.element('#myDiv').trigger('click');
 });
```

I want "myDiv" to be clicked with the 'REAL MOUSE CLICK' on page reload. Is there any possible way to do this???

Comment: Have you done any research on this before asking?

Comment: Why don't you just trigger the action that a click would do, rather than the click?

Comment: You can try jquery's trigger

Comment: [Creating and triggering events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

Comment: Actually i want the real mouse click on page reload, since click function doesn't seems to do so as the real mouse click. so my doubt it, is there any possible way to trigger real mouse click automatically??

Comment: No! there is no possibility. If that is the case then there is no difference between real mouse click and fake mouse click

Comment: Oh k  i was confused with these two.. Thanks...